# Do 山人 and 仙人 have the same meaning of they mean different things?

Tags: nuances, compounds

I find that the compounds mean "mountain people" or "hermit". Do these words have some difference in meaning or do they actually mean exactly the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't typically consider these the same words, despite similar origins.

山人 {やまびと} to me specifically refers to people living in the mountains, as hermits or in small villages.

仙人 {せんにん} implies hermit, but actually might have a meaning closer to sage, enlightened one, or wizard ("wizard" might be derived from Taoism).

Comment: This is why 亀仙人 (aka Master Roshi) lives on an island in the middle of the sea :)

Comment: @naruto I didnt the question having Master Roshi in mind.